# How can I get all DataEntity data from Dynamics AX(Finance and Operations)?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax7

I tried the X++, but it seems that X++ can only query the Entity from the reference packages. If I created another package with custom Entity, I have to append new reference in the X++ code package. It has a lot of manual actions.

I also tried the OData Service, but the Entity with **IsPublic=No** cannot be queried from OData Service.

Is there any other method to get all DataEntity data from Dynamics AX (Finance and Operations)? I'm working on the Dynamics Finance and Operations.

Thanks a lot,
Tilerphy

Comment: What are you trying to achieve from this? Odata service can be used for real time integrations and Data management can be used for other integrations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @PradeepMuttikulangaraVasu . Maybe OData service is better for me, because I need to query all entity data  with some filters. I know the Data Import and Export of Data Management, but it seems that it cannot apply filters or conditions.

Comment: @PradeepMuttikulangaraVasu but the OData service will ignore the Entity with IsPublic=No. So that, I cannot get all the entity data via OData service. Any other method?

Comment: What is the business need? As per the need, you need to decide the integration pattern.

Comment: Hello @PradeepMuttikulangaraVasu, it is for a backup and restore type solution. Basically we are looking for a way to be able to query for all Data Entities at Dynamics F&O. OData is perfect for this job and it is what we using for other MS services. However for Dynamics F&O, unfortunately a lot of data entities which customer wants us to backup is with IsPublic as No and we are exploring other ways for this work as well.  For Data Management, it looks like that Data project needs to be created manually and there are so many data entities in Dynamics F&O. Thanks very much for your insights.

Comment: My suggestion will be to create custom data entities  in new model for those which are not set as public. Not sure if you have explored https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/analytics/export-entities-to-your-own-database

Comment: Thanks @PradeepMuttikulangaraVasu. We could use it as one option for backup although I haven't found a way to restore the data in this way.